# Module Error Requiring unknown module

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello am having a problem I am using react native am a newbie and I am creating a app that has some tabs but what i want is when i click the tab each as its own navigation bar. 
I follow [AppCoda Example][1] but i notice that code base is different from the new code base react native. my code is bellow. Remember am trying to get a Nav bar for each tabs an i created a folder structure to require each tab in but am getting that unknown module when i know its there. Just to add if i add the same code which was in sub folder in the index.os.js it works look below:

```
    'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var SearchButton = require('./app/components/buttons/searchButton');
var CameraButton = require('./app/components/buttons/cameraButton');
var ProfileButton = require('./app/components/buttons/profileButton');
var ContactButton = require('./app/components/buttons/contactButton');



var {
  AppRegistry,
  TabBarIOS,
  NavigatorIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} = React;



class AwesomeProject extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    selectedTab: 'Search'
    };

  }



 render() {

   return (
     <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab} barTintColor="darkslateblue">
           <TabBarIOS.Item
               selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Search'}
               systemIcon="search"
               onPress={() => {
               this.setState({
               selectedTab: 'Search'
               });
           }} style={styles.container} >


      <SearchButton/>
       </TabBarIOS.Item>



         <TabBarIOS.Item systemIcon="bookmarks"
         selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Camera'}
         icon={{uri:'Camera'}}
         onPress={() => {
         this.setState({
         selectedTab: 'Camera'
         });
       }}>

      <CameraButton/>
       </TabBarIOS.Item>


         <TabBarIOS.Item systemIcon="history"
         selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Profile'}
         icon={{uri:'Profile'}}
         onPress={() => {
         this.setState({
         selectedTab: 'Profile'
         });
       }}>
      <ProfileButton/>
       </TabBarIOS.Item>

          <TabBarIOS.Item systemIcon="contacts"
         selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Contacts'}
         icon={{uri:'Contacts'}}
         onPress={() => {
         this.setState({
         selectedTab: 'Contacts'
         });
       }}>
      <ContactButton/>
       </TabBarIOS.Item>


   </TabBarIOS>
);

  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({

  navigator: {
        flex: 1,
       },
  tabContent: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center', },
        tabText: {
        color: 'white',
        margin: 50, },

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Now in the search button which should get the search title from a navigation folder thats where the problem is its saying unknown module

```
'use strict'; 

var React = require('react-native');
var searchTitle = require('./app/components/navigation/searchTitle');


var {

StyleSheet,
View,
NavigatorIOS,
Text

} = React


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
navigator: {
flex: 1
}
}
);


class Search extends React.Component{
  render() {

     return (
        <NavigatorIOS
     style={styles.navigator}
    initialRoute={{
      title: 'SomeTitle',
      component: searchTitle
      }}/>

   );


 }

}


module.exports = Search;
```

can some one help me with this.

Comment: If you could somehow give us a snapshot of the file structure, as well as the contents of searchTitle.js, that would help a lot.

Comment: here is a snapchat [Snapchat you need](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfz4vhp00ljmmb2/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-06%20at%2010.38.42%20AM.png?dl=0)

Comment: @NaderDabit IsaacMadwed solve it but am getting a blank screen not showing the content or title

Answer (score 0):

You are asking `require` to search a relative path.  From your examples I see that `searchButton` is in `./app/components/buttons/` and `searchTitle` is in `./app/components/navigation/`, so if you want to require `searchTitle` from `searchButton` the path you need to specify is `../navigation/searchTitle`.

Comment: that doesn't work i tried that the search button is the one that get the title the code works if i remove the folders but i need folders to structure the code seemlessly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  Change `require('./app/components/navigation/searchTitle')` to `require('../navigation/searchTitle')`.  `require` is searching a relative path and so is trying to find searchTitle in `./app/components/buttons/navigation/searchTitle`.

Comment: Yah it found the searchTitle component but there is a problem no title at the top. Also the content/body is not visible am currently trying to debug to see whats up

Answer (score 0):

var back_bg = require('./../img/menu.png');